# Why Jest not working as expected after upgrading to the latest version 27.5.1?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I have an existing repo that uses NestJs as base framework and Jest for testing. I am trying to upgrade the package versions and after upgrading jest to the latest version, my existing tests are not passing and also jest is not working as expected. Below is my code (reduced to only capture the errors I am having)

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";

describe("OptinOptoutService", () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let optinOptoutService: OptinOptoutService;
  let userOptinService: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    userOptinService = {
      isUserOptedIn: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
      getUserOptInDocument: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
          customerId: "some-customer-id",
          isOptedIn: true,
        })
      ),
      updateOptInStatus: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    };

    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // module imports here
      ],
      providers: [
        OptinOptoutService,
        {
          provide: UserOptinService,
          useValue: userOptinService, // using my mock here
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    userOptinService = module.get(UserOptinService);
    optinOptoutService = module.get(OptinOptoutService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  describe("handleOptIn", () => {
    it("should return data if already opted-in", async () => {
      // Setup a mock user that's already opted in
      const getUserOptInDocumentSpy = jest.spyOn(
        userOptinService,
        "getUserOptInDocument"
      );
      const result = await optinOptoutService.handleOptIn(user, "idType");
      expect(result).toEqual({
        licenceNumber: "licenceNumber",
        licenceType: "someType",
      });

      // this was working with jest v26.0.1, now not working with jest v27.5.1
      expect(getUserOptInDocumentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

      // had to add setTimeout() like below to get the above test pass
      // setTimeout(() => expect(getUserOptInDocumentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1), 1);
    });

    it("should throw photocard error if RMS throws RMS_NO_ELIGIBLE_PRODUCTS", async () => {
      expect.assertions(2);

      // this was working with jest v26.0.1, now with jest v27.5.1, it keeps using the
      // mock implementation that I have in beforeEach() block
      jest
        .spyOn(userOptinService, "getUserOptInDocument")
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(null));

      try {
        await optinOptoutService.handleOptIn(user, "idType");
      } catch (error: any) {
        expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(CustomError);
        expect(error.message).toEqual("Custom error message.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried some comments inside code to help you understand the problems bit better (I hope). My `current package.json` file

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.6",
    "@nestjs/common": "8.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "8.4.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "8.4.0",
    "@types/express": "4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/jest-when": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "5.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.13.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "class-transformer": "0.3.1",
    "comment-json": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "26.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-regex": "1.8.0",
    "express": "4.17.3",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-when": "^3.0.1",
    "jose": "2.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.3.0",
    "mongoose": "6.2.4",
    "node-mocks-http": "1.11.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "7.1.0",
    "strong-mock": "^6.0.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.3",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.6.2",
    "winston": "3.2.1",
    "winston-transport": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "prettier -l --write",
      "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext .ts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/tough-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-serial-runner": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs-etc": "^10.6.2",
    "weak-napi": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "mongodbMemoryServer": {
      "version": "latest",
      "debug": false
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "**/follow-redirects": "^1.14.7",
    "**/node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
  }
}
```

My `old package.json` file

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@nestjs/common": "7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/core": "7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "7.2.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.3.2",
    "@nestjs/testing": "7.3.1",
    "@types/express": "4.17.7",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.4",
    "@types/jest-when": "^2.7.2",
    "@types/node": "14.0.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "comment-json": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-regex": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-when": "^3.0.1",
    "jose": "1.27.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.3.0",
    "mongoose": "5.13.9",
    "node-mocks-http": "1.8.1",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "strong-mock": "^6.0.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.9.6",
    "winston": "3.2.1",
    "winston-transport": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "prettier -l --write",
      "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext .ts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.7.11",
    "@types/tough-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-serial-runner": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs-etc": "^10.5.2",
    "weak-napi": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "mongodbMemoryServer": {
      "version": "latest"
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "**/follow-redirects": "^1.14.7",
    "**/node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
  }
}
```

Please suggest what am I missing here. Thanks

Comment: can someone please explain the reason behind voting to close this question?

Comment: If you go to a mechanic and just say "My car's not working" do you expect them to be much help? Same applies here: you just say "it's not working". __Give details__! _How_ is it not working? What errors do you have? What are you expecting? And please, add syntax highlighing to your code bloicks

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel sorry if my question is unclear to you, I wish you had gone through the code I have provided. There are comments in the code block where I clearly mentioned what is not working like this `it keeps using the mock implementation that I have in beforeEach() block`

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, but I guess you should at least provide error logs and outcomes of the test run. In my case I am using `mswjs` for mocking and some update started triggering `Error: Cookie has domain set to the public suffix "localhost" which is a special use domain.`. It says its from `tough-cookie` jest dependency, but I cannot find anything more about it.